# Better way to get accurate location than using CoreLocation all the time?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, geolocation, core-location

Right now we're using CoreLocation to get your GPS location. It sends it to the server once every 90 seconds. To help with battery drain we change the accuracy to the lowest possible until 30 seconds before the update is going to be sent and then change it to `[locationHelper switchToBestAccuracy];`. Is there a more battery efficient way to get these location updates?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know how to comment on this without knowing what you're doing in a little more detail. There may be a better way to manage the location querying and server back and forth but it will depend on what your app does. Is it giving directions? Do you need to know where the user is EXACTLY (down to the foot) every 90 seconds? Or is it ok if the user only tells you when they've moved more than 20 feet? 100 feet? Please provide more details - thanks!

Comment: We need to know where the user is down to within a few meters. We're tracking who is around each other at all times.

Comment: I think this is going to depend on measurements then. I would run the app on the same device, with no other apps running, walk around ( or bike or whatever) and see how the battery burns. I would say that 30 seconds may be too long - you may be able to get by staying on kCLLocationAccuracyBest for only 10 seconds. Measurements are the best way to go in this case I think.